# How to name the intermediate entity lists in a LINQ query?

Tags: c#, linq

I need help with a specific LINQ query. I couldn't find a way to group intermediate entities and use them in my select statement.

The domain: We have a list of criteria `Question`s to assess `Project`s. There are `Assessor`s that assess the projects and give them `QuestionScore`s which include notes. When an assessor is assessing a project, they should be able to see other assessor's notes. Assessors also are able to reassess, then they also see their previous note.

I wrote the following query for this that will return a list of `QuestionModel`s, however, I don't know how to fill some of the parts.

```
string assessorId = "assessor_id_0";
string projectId = "project_id_0";

var query = 
from question in _context.Questions
join questionScore in _context.QuestionScores on question.Id equals questionScore.QuestionId
join assessment in _context.Assessments on questionScore.AssessmentId equals assessment.Id
where assessment.ProjectId == projectId
select new QuestionModel
{
    Id = question.Id,
    QuestionOrder = question.QuestionOrder,
    QuestionText = question.QuestionText,
    SelfNote = null, // Assessor's old note
    OtherNotes = null // Other assessors' notes
};
```

How do I fill the null parts?

Here are my domain classes:

```
public class Question
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public int QuestionOrder { get; set; }
    public string QuestionText { get; set; }
}

public class QuestionScore
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string AssessmentId { get; set; }
    public string QuestionId { get; set; }
    public string AssessmentNote { get; set; }
}

public class Assessment
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string ProjectId { get; set; }
    public string AssessorId { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: If you want fields from table `Assessor`, wouldn't it be better to put this table in your join? I guess `Assesment.AssessorId` refers to the Assessor that did this `Assesment`.

Comment: @harald coppoolse I dont need fields from the assessor table. AssossorId given is enough the distinguish between self note and other notes using the foreign key Assessment.AssessorId

Comment: Well the question says: `SelfNote = null, // Assessor's old note`. If not from the Assessor, where else do you get the `Assessor's old note` from?

Comment: All notes are given by an assessor to a question in an assessment. All notes are in QuestionScore.AssessmentNote. Questions never change. Every assessor can assess every project.